# How to convert mattermodeling stackexchange answer citation to ACS format?

Tags: support

My [Question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8883/how-to-add-molecules-to-a-specific-location-in-periodic-box-using-gromacs) was answered by the [User](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/181/b-kelly), now I need to cite the answer to my thesis. However, citation text obtained as,

*B. Kelly (https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/181/b-kelly), How to add molecules to a specific location in periodic box using gromacs?, URL (version: 2022-04-03): https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8892*

My thesis references should be in ACS format only. How can I do this? Is there any site mechanism for this? Also in future how can I change the referencing format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very good question. I've been meaning to push the company to improve the citation feature, for a long time now. However, they often take years to do what we would think is an extremely simple thing, or they completely reject the "feature" request. They won't even add 1 line in the MathJax script so that we can use AMS style LaTeX with automatic equation numbering.

Getting things done sometimes requires a lot of campaigning (and organizing ourselves so that we can demonstrate how many of us want a certain change to be implemented). There will probably not be any "site mechanism" to do what you want with the citation feature, for a long time.

As for your question about how to cite this answer, you will have to convert it to ACS format yourself.

I typed all relevant information into [***Citation Machine***'s ACS citation generator](https://www.citationmachine.net/american-chemical-society):

[image]

The result I got was:

> Kelly, B. https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8892 (accessed May 29,  2022).

Which is underwhelming because it doesn't include the publication date of 3 April 2022, nor the "article title" which is the title of the Q/A thread. I guess that's how ACS wants it. Luckily it's just a thesis, so you can ask the institution hosting your thesis studies (or simply your thesis supervisor) if you can deviate from the ACS format in this case, **or you can just do whatever you want, knowing that the worst possible consequence is that they actually notice this, and ask you to change it.**

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer